# Access single DLL from multiple classes

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm relatively new to Java, and as such am very new to JNI and C++. Is it possible to access the same dynamic library over multiple classes? For instance, if in my C++, I had a class that in turn had two children classes, would I be able to access the child classes from two Java classes?

For example, in foo.h:

```
class Controller {
    public:
        class A {
            public:
                int someMethod();
        }
        class B {
            public:
                int someOtherMethod();
        }
}
```

and in A.java:

```
class A {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("foo");
    }
    public native int someMethod();
}
```

with B.java:

```
class B {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("foo");
    }
    public native int someOtherMethod();
}
```

Would this be possible? and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: It's kind of unclear to me what you're asking.  If you literally mean a DLL or shared object file, then of course.  The JVM can link to a single library and all classes share that library.  If you're talking about a running program though (i.e., one with instances on the heap) that might be a little tougher.  I'd look at FIFOs or a pipe myself.  IPC (Inter-Process Communication) might be better than JNI here.

Comment: Is your question about how to map C++ classes to Java classes, as one could accomplish with, for example, tools such as [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) or [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp)?

Comment: JNI doesn't care about your C++ classes.

Comment: @SamuelAudet, I was going to look into SWIG, but it seemed to have quite a difficult setup. Being new to C++, it all seemed a bit intimidating. Although, I've heard that it is much better to use when involved in large projects, in which this one is quite large (for my standards). The project that I'm trying to access in Java is upwards of 45 different classes.

**EDIT:** just looked into JavaCPP and it looks very promising.

Comment: You've done it. Just ensure that the native methods of A and B are both linked into foo.dll.

Comment: @RussellHueske If you have questions about the mapping between C++ classes and Java classes, then they are specific to the tool you use (SWIG etc); as I said before, JNI doesn't interact with your C++ classes in any way (it only calls global functions).

Comment: @immibus well my goal here is to create a bridge to an existing project (not written by me), as well as edit the information as needed to get the data through JNI. Would this (in theory) work?

Comment: Certainly, I did it last century. But there is no specific question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes? Yes. Instances? Yes (but it's up to you to share them and if you're using multiple threads, and assuming they are not reentrant, you would need to synchronize access).

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you are accessing functions from a DLL not really instances of classes.

You can call external functions from inside class methods or in free standing functions, whether they reside in a DLL, Shared Library or another translation unit.

So, yes, you can access methods of other classes provided they have public accessibility and a declaration (prototype) is available before the methods are used.